# cakephp backbone save not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, cakephp, backbone.js

I have a site developed in cakephp where I'm using a simple app in backbone.
Now I would like to save data from backbone but doesn't work, return always inside callback error, and it doens't take the right value to save inside table.

This is my simple app:

```
TaskModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
        url: function(){
            return "/step_task/ajax_save";
        }
    });

    TaskCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model: TaskModel,
        initData: function(data){
            return data;
        }
    });

    var TaskView = Backbone.View.extend({ 
        template: _.template($("#task-template").html()),
        initialize: function(){ 
            this.task = new TaskCollection(<?php echo json_encode($step['StepTask']); ?>);
            this.render();
        }, 
        render: function(){
            taskModel = new TaskModel({
                'id': '1',
                'user_id': '1'
            });
//--------------------------- here I would like to save inside my table ----------------
                taskModel.save(null, {
                    success: function(model, response) {
                        console.log('success');
                        console.log(model);
                        console.log(response);
                    },
                    error: function(model, response) {
                        console.log('error');
                        console.log(model);
                        console.log(response);
                    },
                    wait: true // Add this
                });
                $(this.el).html(this.template({tasks: this.task.models}));
            }
        });
```

and this is my funciton inside StepTaskController.php

```
public function ajax_save(){
    $this->autoRender = false;
    $this->StepTask->save($this->request->data);
}
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: No error in console but return inside the callback error and itdoesn''take right value to save

Comment: What's the HTTP status in the response? It doesn't look like you're responding with anything. Try responding with json. See this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1226330/how-to-return-the-correct-content-type-for-json-in-cakephp).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change the `url` in your model to `urlRoot` :

```
TaskModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    urlRoot: '/step_task/ajax_save'
});
```

Comment: I think isn't a problem of url because I have seen that I enter inside the function of the controller, don't know if is that the problem

Comment: So what does `console.log(model);` and `console.log(response);` prints to the console ?

Comment: console.log(model) print the model, and inside console.log(response) i see an array where inside responseText there is the echo that I send from my controller. But always is inside callback error because I see inside console the error log message console.log('error');

Comment: I think that the problem come from your server, try to test it without the backbone model.

Comment: ok but how can I take right value inside my function? Because I can't print value from backbone model inside it I can't understand it

Comment: inside the controller to take post value and insert into my table

Comment: In the Chrome Developer Tools -> Network tab, look at your request server response, what is the `Status Code` you got there ?